# Running an insert script from multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a pretty simple script that does the following: Takes the id of a content module and assigns it to multiple locations

So say I click the link on a content module with ID of 123, I want to assign it to all multiple locations. In SQL I would just say :

```
INSERT INTO table (cont_id,loc_id) 
VALUES (123, select(id from location_table where active = 1))
```

I'm currently using this:

```
$pageID = $_GET['pageID'];

$assignPage = "
INSERT INTO locationContent(page_id, display_id)
    VALUES ( '$pageID', select(id from locations where active = 1))
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active = 1
";

$performAssign = $mysqlConn->query($assignPage);
```

The issue I'm wondering about though, is do I need to put this into a foreach or while loop? If I were to just run as is, I feel like that would only work for one record

Comment: what does the locationContent table look like?

Comment: location content just has columns (id, page_id, display_id). Simply relational between content IDs and location IDs

Comment: Okay the mysql knowlege needs to come from someone else. I'm not sure how that SQL statement would be interpreted. May I suggest building temp tables? If it were an iterative loop what would you change each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix the `INSERT INTO .. VALUES` and `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax, however `SELECT constant, var FROM ..` is possible like:

```
$assignPage = $mysqlConn->prepare("
INSERT INTO locationContent(page_id, display_id)
    SELECT :page as page_id, id FROM locations WHERE active = 1
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active = 1
";

$performAssign = $assignPage->execute(array('page' =>$pageID));
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for [MySQL `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html).

From the documentation:

> With `INSERT ... SELECT`, you can quickly insert many rows into a table from the result of a SELECT statement, which can select from one or many tables.

Query:

```
INSERT INTO locationContent (page_id, display_id)
SELECT ?, id FROM locations WHERE active = 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active = 1
```

The `?` stands for parameter `$pageID` (you do want to use parameterized queries and prepared statement to protect your code against SQL injection).